React Youtube card. Playbutton not rendering properly in CSS
I have below example where I am trying to render a YouTube card. The issue I am facing is that the play button white background is not adjusting into the play icon that I am setting through my CSS styles. I am trying to undertand why that is not working.
Also, when I hover the card, I should see a background that says Video Test, but that never gets rendered.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ndu1t6?file=src%2Fexample.tsx,src%2FYoutubeCard.tsx
Why is this part giving the trouble?
'&:hover': {
  transform: 'scale(1.05)',
  boxShadow: '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
},
'&:hover $overlay': {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
},
'&:hover $textOverlay': {
  opacity: 1,
},
'&:hover $playButton': {
  opacity: 0,
},


Not sure if this helps, but moving the different hover styles that are applied to overlay, textOverlay and 'playButton' outside of the card style (so that you no longer specify them via the $) helps to at least show the text when hovering over the button.

@CarstenCodes is there a chance you could help me with that comment? I tried something like that before and that did not work either

I think the underlying issues are:

Specificity: some of your styled are being overwritten by the fluentui css styled. By adding !important you can force your styles to be used.
The overlay, textOverlay and playButton should probably not be seperated into sibling div-elements, instead you can group them together.

Here is my code (although the styling might not be exactly what you intended to do):


import { makeStyles } from '@fluentui/react-components';

export const useVideoYoutubeCardStyles = makeStyles({
    card: {
        width: '300px',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        borderRadius: '8px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s',
        '&:hover': {
            transform: 'scale(1.05)',
            boxShadow: '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        },
    },
    overlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        transition: 'background-color 0.3s',
        '&:hover': {
            // backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)', <-- moved this to textOverlay:hover
        },
    },
    textOverlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontWeight: 100,
        textAlign: 'center',
        opacity: 0,
        transition: 'opacity 0.3s',
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

        '&:hover': {
            opacity: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)' //<-- this comes from overlay
        },
    },
    playButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '30%',
        left: '30%',
        width: '100px !important', //<-- add !important because they are otherwise being overwritten
        height: '100px !important', //<-- add !important because they are otherwise being overwritten
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        boxShadow: '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        transition: 'opacity 0.3s',
    },
    playButtonTriangle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '37px',
        top: '28px',
        width: '30px',
        height: '0px',
        borderLeft: '30px solid gray',
        borderTop: '20px solid transparent',
        borderBottom: '20px solid transparent',
        marginLeft: '3px',
    },
});





import { Card, CardPreview, Image } from '@fluentui/react-components';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useVideoYoutubeCardStyles } from './YoutubeCard.styled.tsx';

export type YoutubeCardProps = {
    card: string;
};
export const YoutubeCard: React.FC<YoutubeCardProps> = React.memo((_) => {
    const styles = useVideoYoutubeCardStyles();
    const videoId = 'h3BKjZMGoIw';
    const thumbnailUrl = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg`;

    const handleCardClick = () => {
        window.open(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`, '_blank');
    };

    return (
        <Card className={styles.card} onClick={handleCardClick}>
            <CardPreview>
                <Image
                    src={thumbnailUrl}
                    alt="YouTube Thumbnail"
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />
                {/*black overlay when hovering*/}
                <div className={styles.overlay}></div>
                <div id="textOverlay" className={styles.textOverlay}>
                    <p style={{margin: 0}}>Video Test</p>
                    <div id="playButton" className={styles.playButton}>
                        <div className={styles.playButtonTriangle}></div>
                    </div>
                    {/*    <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>Vide Test Test</p>*/}
                </div>
            </CardPreview>
        </Card>
    );
});

YoutubeCard.displayName = 'YoutubeCard';




Thank you, @Carsten Codes! Marked your answer as the correct one. I am still facing some issues hiding the play button, but this is much closer to what I was looking for, as it shows the overlay text.
This is how it turned out for me after some small edits in case you have more ideas how to hide the play button: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ndu1t6-ku4mk9?file=src%2FYoutubeCard.styles.tsx,src%2FYoutubeCard.tsx

I tried many ways to handle the nested code issue and checked the documentation, but I could not find any way to style the child on parent hover inside makeStyles. Finally, I use a similar package called react-jss to style elements.
NOTE: Some property is not working because they are override by fluent ui so I have added !important in many properties without it properties will not be applied.
You can use react-jss package to achieve your output:
Install react-jss package:
npm i react-jss

// YoutubeCard.styles.tsx
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss"

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    card: {
        width: "300px",
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
        borderRadius: "8px",
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "relative",
        cursor: "pointer",
        transition: "transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s",
        "&:hover": {
            transform: "scale(1.05)",
            boxShadow: "0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            "& $overlay": {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)",
            },
            "& $textOverlay": {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            "& $playButton": {
                opacity: 0,
            },
        },
    },
    overlay: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        transition: "background-color 0.3s",
    },
    textOverlay: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        color: "white",
        opacity: 0,
        transition: "opacity 0.3s",

        height: "100%",
        display: "flex !important", // Without !important property override
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    playButton: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        width: "3rem !important",
        height: "3rem !important",
        display: "flex !important",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        transition: "opacity 0.3s",
    },
    playButtonTriangle: {
        width: "50%",
        height: "50%",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        marginLeft: ".5rem",
        clipPath: "polygon(78% 52%, 0 0, 0 100%)",
    },
})

export default useStyles

// YoutubeCard.tsx
import { Card, CardPreview, Image } from "@fluentui/react-components"
import * as React from "react"
import useStyles from "./YoutubeCard.styles"

export type YoutubeCardProps = {
    card: string
}

export const YoutubeCard: React.FC<YoutubeCardProps> = React.memo((_) => {
    const videoId = "h3BKjZMGoIw"
    const thumbnailUrl = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg`
    const styles = useStyles()

    const handleCardClick = () => {
        window.open(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`, '_blank');
    }

    return (
        <Card className={styles.card} onClick={handleCardClick}>
            <CardPreview>
                <Image
                    src={thumbnailUrl}
                    alt="YouTube Thumbnail"
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                />
                <div className={styles.overlay}></div>
                <div className={styles.textOverlay}>
                    <p>Video Test</p>
                    <p>Vide Test Test</p>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.playButton}>
                    <div className={styles.playButtonTriangle}></div>
                </div>
            </CardPreview>
        </Card>
    )
})

YoutubeCard.displayName = "YoutubeCard"


Marking as correct answer. Unfortunately I can't use that NPM package in my project so I am still having the issue with the overlay-text, but the solution is 100% correct though.
If you run into some other ideas how to make the overlay-text working, please let me know. Thanks!
